# How to get illumination pass from a Smoke Sim with Cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation

Cycles can now render smoke and fire simulation but for compositing need, I want the illumination pass from the fire. The aim is to composite this pass with a tracked footage.

I already try with the diffuse indirect pass but there is the ground plane with it so it's hard without alpha to get a proper image.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to add a material index to your fire's material, and then, on the compositor,  you can take the *Emission* pass, and multiply it with the *Object Index* one.

[image]

Go to the *Properties* panel, then switch to the *Materials* tab, and under the *Settings* subsection, change the material index.

[image]

Then, still on the Properties panel, switch to the *Render Layers* tab, go to the *Passes* subsection and activate *Material Index* and *Emission*.

[image]

Then, in the compositor, multiply the output of a *IDMask* set to 1 and the *Emission* pass.